# Kivy Screenmanager Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to create a mobile app with multiple screen (one of these with camara object embedded), using kivy, but the code below, produces only a black window, without showing nothing.
Can you please help me figuring out why this isn't working?

```
    import kivy, ctypes
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

    class camera(Screen):
        def build(self):
            #camera obj
            self.camera_obj = Camera()
            self.camera_obj.resolution = (800,800)

            #button obj
            button_go_back = Button(text = "go back")
            button_go_back.size_hint = (.5,.2)
            button_go_back.pos_hint = {"x": .25, "y": .25}
    
            #layout
            layout = BoxLayout()
            layout.add_widget(self.camera_obj)
            layout.add_widget(button_go_back)

            return layout

    class MainWindow(Screen):
        def build(self):
            button_take_picture = Button(text = "take a picture")
            button_take_picture.size_hint = (.5,.2)
            button_take_picture.pos_hint = {"x": .25, "y": .25}

            layout = BoxLayout()
            lab = Label(text="some text")
            layout.add_widget(button_take_picture)
            layout.add_widget(lab)

            return layout


    screen_manager=ScreenManager()
    screen_manager.add_widget(MainWindow(name='main'))
    screen_manager.add_widget(camera(name='camera'))

    class NMS(App):
        def build(self):
            return screen_manager
    

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
        NMS().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initializing the `Screen`s in python you might need the `__init__` constructor not build (as far as I'm aware there is no default method named `build` for `Screen` widget).

Thus you may change `MainWindow` to something like this,

```py
class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        button_take_picture = Button(text = "take a picture")
        button_take_picture.size_hint = (.5,.2)
        button_take_picture.pos_hint = {"x": .25, "y": .25}

        layout = BoxLayout()
        lab = Label(text="some text")
        layout.add_widget(button_take_picture)
        layout.add_widget(lab)
        self.add_widget(layout) # Add all those in this screen.
```

Similar rule applies for other screen(s).

Comment: It worked, thank you!